# Getting selected option to display with Semantic UI dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I am having some problems with Semantic UI dropdown menus:

1. I cannot seem to get jquery to work on it. I tried to add the class named "tagline" to it, which will trigger an alert when it is clicked, but it does not work. The class "tagline" when added to other elements, however, works just fine
2. I cannot get the selected value from the menu option to be displayed. When I tried: `$('#idDropDown').dropdown('get value'));`, it gives me the result "object Object". Here is the code:

show.ejs:

```
<% include ../partials/header %>
<div class = "container-fluid text-center" style = "margin-top: 100px;">
    <h1 class = "student-title">Student's homepage</h1>
</div>

<!-- Testing -->
<div class = "container text-center student-list">
    <div id = "dropdownMenu" class="ui fluid search selection dropdown">
        <input type="hidden" name="student">
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="default text">Select a student</div>
        <div class="menu">
            <% students.forEach(function(student) { %>
                <div class = "item" value = "<%=student._id%>" >
                    <%= student.name.first %> <%= student.name.last %>
                </div>
            <% }); %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
<!-- End of div-->


<% include ../partials/footer %>
```

main.js

```
/* global $ */

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
});

$(".tagline").on("click", function() {
    getValue();
    // console.log(test);
});

$('.message .close').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.message').fadeOut();
});



function getValue(){
    alert($('ui.dropdown').dropdown('get value'));
}
```

I am using Semantic UI for the first time since it is a lot more customizable and has a lot more components (I think). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

EDIT:

1. Here is the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7hw9txns/1/

2. Regarding my question 1, jQuery is working just fine here, but it isn't working in my application in Cloud9 IDE (jQuery works with any other components in any page of my application, just not this specific page and dropdown menu)

Comment: Take a look at this JQuery Plugin, it is very easy to use and customize: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I do want to know why my code wasn't working though. Also, I am using Semantic UI for the whole application so I would like to keep it consistent. Thank you again!

Comment: You should provide a fiddle or a snippet, in that way we could see the functionality of your code. In this way, I could see what is not working with your code.

Comment: As for informing you, value attribute is not valid on div element! You could use data-value="" instead.

Comment: I read some documentation in Semantic Ui, there is a callback "onChange(value, text, $choice)", this takes as a parameter the value of a selected element. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the replies! I have added the jsfiddle

Comment: Look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7hw9txns/9/

Comment: Thank you so much @TeutaKoraqi

Comment: U are welcome! :)

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi but do you know why the method I used was not working though ? It is from the official Semantic document guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that your code was ok, but it was not working, because you did not call that behavior on your `dropdown` id, but you called in a general name (`ui.dropdown`). 
I read in that `plugin` that:

`Get value`(**behavior**) - Returns current dropdown input value 
 *In this case, it only returns two letters of the selected option.*

`Get text` (**behavior**) - Returns current dropdown text 
  *In this case, it returns the whole selected text to each item on `dropdown`*.

Finally, here is the fiddle I changed: [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/7hw9txns/12/)

Hope I've been clear!